# How can update ProgressBar and UI when using AsynTask in android

Tags: android-progressbar

I am using progress bar as well as showing completed process percentage in textview. But problem is generated force close when i use txtview.setText(proc+"% Completed") in doInBackground. I think using AsynTask UI not update but we need to update. So please give me a proper solution for that. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Finally I got solution for that. I used following code. Its simple '@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      txtPercMsg.setText(values[0] + "% completed");
      progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
}'